# Updating Build Action for Multiple Procedures in Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-data-tools, alter

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2019.

After I import the database, the signature for a procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SnapDump.ReadApplicationInformation
    @ApplicationInformationID int = null,
    @SnapDumpID int = null,
    @IsActive bit = 1
AS 
BEGIN
```

When I change `CREATE` to `ALTER`, I get the following error:

> SQL70001 :: This statement is not recognized in this context.

If I go to the Properties of the procedure and change the Build Action from "Build" to "None" the error goes away.

I have 80 procedures in this project. Is there a faster way to change the Build Action of all of them other than one at a time?

Thank you

Comment: You should store only CREATE statements in SSDT (Visual Studio) project. If Build action is set to None then SSDT simply ignores these scripts and they will not be added to the deployment or any other SSDT validation and integration.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitrrij. Currently, we are not using SSDT validation or integration for deployment as we have just started using Database projects. Our DBA has a different process for generating update scripts. Our goal at this point is to have a history of changes stored in TFS.

Comment: Then there is no point of having SSDT project if you are not using any of it's functionality.

Comment: Actually, with all due respect, there is a point. It's helping us keep a history of the changes. If a change causes problems, it's much easier to roll back that change.

Comment: why to put it to SSDT? Just put the scripts to the separate folders and put it under source control. You'll have all the history

Comment: anyway, if you want to do that strange thing, then just open project sqlproj file and modify it manually. It is simple XML and all such settings as Build None or Include are stored there

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted to know. I put it in SSDT as a safeguard in case another developer changes the proc directly in the database rather than checking out and opening the file. I run a compare on a regular basis to look for such differences.

Comment: You are welcome, but just in case ... You are doing something wrong.

Comment: If I understand the Code of Conduct correctly, your comments are judgmental and inappropriate. My use of SSDT is serving my purposes for where my company is at in terms of source control. To call it a "strange thing" or to tell me that I'm doing something wrong is unacceptable.